# How to find the length of an object in a matrix?

Tags: java, eclipse

I created a matrix containing the following data:

```
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Folowing this code I have determined number of the objects in the given plan (7 obejcts. Object are considered a group of 1's)

```
public static void nrofObjects(int[][] matrix)
{
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            if (matrix[i][j] == 1)
            {
                if ((i - 1 < 0 || matrix[i - 1][j] == 0) && (j - 1 < 0 || matrix[i][j - 1] == 0))
                {
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("THERE ARE : " + count + " OBJECTS");
}
```

How can i output the length of each object and his position . For example Object nr.1 have length=2 and is in a vertical position.

Comment: Before answering, you should probably review your algorithm to count the number of objects.

Regarding your definition : `Object are considered a group of 1's`
What about this matrix

`
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 \n
0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 \n
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 \n
0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 \n
1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 \n
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 \n
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 \n
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 \n
`

This have 3 objects, your algorithm will return 5.

If you are able to count the object, you will be able to store a list of the size of each object (then number of object will be the length of the list)

Comment: @Thomas Excuse me, I did not express myself correctly , I forgot to add that objects are separated by at least one line of 0’s.

Comment: you algo count line, L, Z or square patterns as 1 object but neiter reverse Z nor reverse L